# How to import enum in typescript with import type

Tags: typescript, types, enums

I work in a project (TS 4.7) where the `importsNotUsedAsValues` flag is set to `error`.

If I import enums as types:

> import type { enum } from "xx"

And use them in my code like so:

> const something = enum.VALUE

the TS compiler complains as importing a type and using it as a value is not permitted (makes sense). But as enums belong to the value scope, not the type one, this creates an interesting pickle. ([See this interesting discussion on GH](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40344))

If I prepend the lines of my code that use the enums with `//@ts-expect-error`, then the compiler ignores the said lines and does not compile them to .js, leaving me with my enums in plain text, leading to errors.

#### TS Code:

```js
import type { AccountStatus } from "@app/types";

await auth.setCustomUserClaims(id, {
  //@ts-expect-error
  account_status: AccountStatus.Pending,
});
```

#### JS Code after compilation:

```js
await auth.setCustomUserClaims(id, {
  account_status: AccountStatus.Pending,
});
```

Conversely, if I drop the `type` and import them as regular dependencies:

> import { enum } from "xx"

then it is my *bundler* that complains as it is looking for a production dependency that should be referenced in the `dependencies` object of my package.json.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm confused. `import type { enum } from "xx"` imports the type of the enum, and `const something: enum.VALUE` uses that type as a type. Then in your second example you import the type `import type { AccountStatus } from "@app/types";` but then use it as a value in an object literal `{ account_status: AccountStatus.Pending }`. When I try to replicate this, it works fine. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-shape-c4w7lv?file=/src/index.ts. Please attempt to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then [edit] your question.

Comment: Point being, if you only need the enum as a type, then import type. If you also need it's values at runtime, then import as normal.

Comment: Alternate approach - `const Roles = {
  Admin: "admin",
  Writer: "writer",
  Reader: "reader"
} as const;`.  Then convert object key in a type - `type RoleKeys = typeof Roles[keyof typeof Roles];`.  See [this opinion](https://dev.to/ivanzm123/dont-use-enums-in-typescript-they-are-very-dangerous-57bh).  I've also see a post by TypeScript project lead saying in hindsight they shouldn't have developed `enum` (which doesn't exist in JS).

Comment: @AlexWayne, I made a typo in the const example that I fixed. I checked your sandbox, it is not the same as the above as you are casting a string. Which means that `const something = 'dontExist'  as enum.VALUE` can be used without errors.  As for importing them "normally", as I mentioned, it is leading to other problems. @CraigHicks, thanks, I will consider this approach moving forward. I have always liked the DX that came with enums, but this issue bit me hard and I can see now slippery they can be.

Comment: if you do `const foo = enum.VALUE` then you are using `enum` as a value and not a type. Which means you can't use import type and you have to do `import { enum } from "xx"; const foo = enum.VALUE` What problems does this cause for you?

Comment: You say "then it is my bundler that complains" what error do you specifically get from your bundler?

Comment: Hi @AlexWayne, this error happened when building Google Cloud Functions and upon deployment I was getting this error `Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@app/types'`. My `@app/types` was there, but in the `devDependencies`.

Comment: Can you import any value from the `@app/types` path or is just this enum thats causing problems? Is your bundler configured to use your tsconfig paths? (I'm asuming that `@app/types` is a custom path alias) For instance, I use this package with vite https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths. This may have _nothing_ to do with being any enum, and just a configuration issue with your bundler.